# Force panGesture of UISCrollView minimumOfTouches to 1 Finger, not 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, zooming, uipangesturerecognizer

I have implemented a UIScrollView in a view with an UIImageView in which I wanted do Zooming & Panning. After Zoom in the Image, I would like to do Panning, but the UIScrollView only responds to the Panning if I use 2 fingers.

I have tried to set the UIPanGesture minimumNumberOfTouches of the UIScrollView to 1, but the UIScrollView does the UIPanGesture like before, only with 2 fingers.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handle the content offset of scroll view instead of using the Pan gesture. This will pan the zoomed image

Comment: Could you explain this please? I have the same issue.